# Automating email to make address specific attachments

Tags: image, email, asp-classic, smtp

Besides programming, I am also a professional photographer. I recently set up an extremely successful photobooth... so successful I have about 500 photos, and a list of 60 emails (some pictures have multiple recipients)to send them to.

Email is the only way I can get the pictures to their respective owner, and I do not have time to manually send each photo to its owner in an email app, nor do I want to risk making mistakes in the process. All of the email addresses are in a text file, with the file locations of each image following the intended recipient. In addition to the pictures, I have one universal body text to send.

I have already looked into ASP, Macros, CDOSys, and some slightly confusing options with SMTP, but answers using these are more than welcome.

Any ideas on how to use the information in the text file to email each recipient with their photos?

tl;dr: I need to get 500 individual photos to 60 email addresses, without sending each picture manually, or giving someone someone else's photos. All of the information is organized in a text file.

Update: I have a few different versions of the text file. I have a text file straight out of a notepad editor, I have a csv file, and I have a version which delimits file paths with # and email addresses with tabs.

Comment: what format is your text file - is it csv?

Answer (score 0):

Using classic asp and web email server and assuming you can have created a csv file.

step 1. upload textFile.csv into server
with say emailAddress, pictureFileAddress etc.

step 2. import and emailer script (classic asp)

```
downloadFile = Server.MapPath("textFile.csv")

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
if objFSO.FileExists(downloadFile) then

    firstLine = true    '... assume first line is header    
    Do Until objFile.AtEndOfLine OR finished
     StrTemp = objFile.ReadLine

     dataArray = Split(StrTemp, ",")   '... assume just two fields for this e.g.
     dataCount = UBound(dataArray)
        email = dataArray(0)
        picturefile = dataArray(1)
         '... perform any data validation or Regexp

        If email <> "" AND firstLine = false then 

         Set myMail=CreateObject("CDO.Message")
         myMail.From = "yourfromemail"
         myMail.ReplyTo = "yourreplyfromemail"
         myMail.Subject = "Your picture"

        '...create target file for attachment
         fn1 = picturefile 
         fn2 = Server.MapPath(fn1)
         myMail.AddAttachment fn2 

         myMail.HTMLBody = strMessage                   
         myMail.Send  
         Set myMail = Nothing              

       end if
       if firstLine then firstline = false
  loop
End if
```

I hope this helps